# Plugin InAppBrowser não funciona (Unknown provider)

Tags: apache-cordova, ionic, inappbrowser

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<input type="text" id="input-url" name="input-url" placeholder="URL do Servidor">
<button class="button button-block button-dark" ng-controller="AppCtrl"
  ng-click="openBrowser()">Definir</button>
```

Código javascript:

```
angular.module('CoffeeForce.controllers',[])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaInAppBrowser, $http, messageFactory) {

  var options = {
     location: 'no',
     clearcache: 'yes',
     toolbar: 'no'
  };

  $scope.openBrowser = function() {
     inputUrl = document.getElementById("input-url").value;

     $cordovaInAppBrowser.open(inputUrl, '_self', options)
     .then(function(event) {
       console.log("success");
     })

     .catch(function(event) {
        console.log("Error")
     });
  });
```

Basicamente, preciso que uma url fornecida pelo usuário seja carregada pelo plugin inAppBrowser, porém, o seguinte erro ocorre:

```
ionic.bundle.js:26794 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cordovaInAppBrowserProvider <- $cordovaInAppBrowser <- AppCtrl
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/unpr?p0=%24cordovaInAppBrowserProvider%20%3C-%20%24cordovaInAppBrowser%20%3C-%20AppCtrl
    at ionic.bundle.js:13438
    at ionic.bundle.js:17788
    at Object.getService [as get] (ionic.bundle.js:17941)
    at ionic.bundle.js:17793
    at getService (ionic.bundle.js:17941)
    at injectionArgs (ionic.bundle.js:17965)
    at Object.invoke (ionic.bundle.js:17987)
    at $controllerInit (ionic.bundle.js:23397)
    at nodeLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:22335)
    at compositeLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:21703)
```

Obs: Se utilizo o código:

```
window.open(url, '_self', 'location=no');
```

Consigo abrir as páginas normalmente, porém estou utilizando a primeira alternativa para validar se a URL é valida ou não antes de carregar uma página inválida pro usuário. Alguma ideia do que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: acredito que esteja faltando algo, tente angular.module('CoffeeForce.controllers',['ngCordova'])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Você não precisa injetar o $cordovaInAppBrowser no controller.
- O error de dependência ocorre porque você possivelmente está usando o ionic serve para emular sua aplicação.
- Adicione o método abaixo que irá solucionar seu problema, porém esse método só vai rodar quando emular diretamente no device.

  ```
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

      function onDeviceReady() {
          window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
          var target = "_blank";
          var options = "location=no";
          var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open($scope.url, target, options);
      }
  ```